# "No devices connected..." error with Turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting a no devices connected error when attempting to launch the kinect. I have turtlebot dashboard up and running in full mode with 0 breaker green. My Kinect is plugged in as well and it looks like the other components are coming on except for the camera. I have also tried "roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch".

turtlebot@turtlebot:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/30c60d6e-a050-11e1-9212-9cb70d1ffd03/roslaunch-turtlebot-5253.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://10.5.6.187:35868/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /kinect_laser/max_height
- /openni_camera/depth_rgb_rotation
- /rosdistro
- /openni_camera/image_mode
- /openni_camera/image_time_offset
- /openni_camera/projector_depth_baseline
- /kinect_laser_narrow/output_frame_id
- /openni_camera/depth_mode
- /kinect_laser_narrow/max_height
- /openni_camera/depth_frame_id
- /openni_camera/depth_time_offset
- /kinect_laser/output_frame_id
- /rosversion
- /openni_camera/depth_registration
- /openni_camera/debayering
- /openni_camera/depth_rgb_translation
- /kinect_laser/min_height
- /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
- /openni_camera/shift_offset
- /kinect_laser_narrow/min_height
- /openni_camera/rgb_frame_id

NODES
/
kinect_breaker_enabler (turtlebot_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py)
openni_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
openni_camera (nodelet/nodelet)
pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)
kinect_laser (nodelet/nodelet)
kinect_laser_narrow (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.5.6.187:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-1]: started with pid [5273]
process[openni_manager-2]: started with pid [5274]
process[openni_camera-3]: started with pid [5275]
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [5276]
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [5277]
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [5292]
[ INFO] [1337280578.058743992]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1337280579.068192604]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[kinect_breaker_enabler-1] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/30c60d6e-a050-11e1-9212-9cb70d1ffd03/kinect_breaker_enabler-1*.log
[ INFO] [1337280580.077305703]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1337280581.086373589]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1337280582.095526630]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34233/%22no-devices-connected...%22-error-with-turtlebot/) by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) on 2012-05-17**:
SOLVED - The power cable down in the bot had wiggled loose.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-17**:
Please post the solution as an "answer" and then accept it once you are able to (in perhaps a week or so I believe it might let you). This will let others easily see that the question has a solution and find the correct solution. Thanks for helping to keep ROS Answers organized and easy to use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The power cable down in the bot had wiggled loose.

Eric - Thanks for notifying me! I am still getting used to the forum.

---

Originally posted by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) with karma: 148 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1